# Unexpected gdal_merge result

Tags: gdal-merge

What I'm trying to do is to merge to geotif files with `gdal_merge`, but the result is not what I expected.

Here are the files I'm trying to merge.

```
gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -o result.tif file1.tif file2.tif
```

[The two tif files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0oNOpRt01j6OVpBc2UxVlZSYms/view)

[image: GeoTiff 1]

[image: GeoTiff]

**The result**

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could share your source files. Something to do with how to handle nodata I guess.

Comment: I added a link to the files.

Comment: How have you created the original ones? If you check them with gdalinfo you'll see that they are 32 bit images without nodata value nor alpha channel `Min=0.598 Max=2.902` I had a try with a few different ways but result was not good for me either.

Comment: I cliped them from a bigger one with gdalwarp and recalculated the values with gdalcalc. The Float32 type of the band is done on purpose, and about the alpha band I can add one but the result is the same.

I think the problem is in the gdalwarp, because after clipping the shapes I want and after tying to merge them the result is the same as the one I posted but with more colors.

gdalwarp of GTiff -cutline shpFile.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha sourceImg.tif outImg.tif

Comment: Drop the ones with alpha so I can have a try with them. BTW, did you use `--NoDataValue=NODATAVALUE`with gdalcalc? I am not sure what the default "datatype specific value" does.